# A problem with div positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

A have something like that:
[alt text http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/9625/88827634.png](http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/9625/88827634.png)

It's OK but i want to add some Title block at the top of Content.

So it can be look like that: 
[alt text http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/9541/31597153.png](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/9541/31597153.png)

I don't know what Title height will be, because there will be some dynamic content.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: post some code and we modify that.

Comment: Keep the height of the Title as auto. That will take the necessary height. Anyway you have the overflow as auto for the content.

Comment: If your title is dynamic, how are you supposed to absolutely position anything underneath it, without creating a scroll bar on the title div?!

Answer (score 1):

why are you positioning all your divs in absolute?

anyways you can wrap Title and Content with 2 divs, the outer div must be in absolute and the inner div is a relative, and you can put an absolute positioning in your Title and Content

```
<div style="position:absolute">
  <div style="position:relative">
      <div style="position:absolute">Title</div>
      <div style="position:absolute">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Figure out the Top and Left of Title and Content, since it will not go outside the green and blue colors of your drawing..

I position absolute the outermost div since you are positioning all your divs in absolute. I assume you already have the measurements for all just like in your first drawing.

Comment: why are you positioning all your divs in absolute?

+1

Comment: since Alex design is all in absolute position. I'm just following what he needs.